# There is error installing Python Package in Pycharm 2019.03 ver

Tags: python, pycharm, package

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mvyv.png)

I installed Python Package "GetOldTweets3" through cmd.
At cmd, the packaged was installed. But Pycharm didn't recognize it.
Attached image is what Pycharm shows about the error. I can't understand it.
How I should to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you see the part where it says `proposed solution`? Did you try doing what it suggests there?

Comment: you probably have a mismatch in version (ie in pycharm your default interpretter is not the same as you had in cmd)